# mySQL data type for form elements

Tags: php, mysql, input

what datatypes do i use for checkboxes and radio buttons and for input type=date in the pmySQL??

```
<pre>
<tr>
   <td class="right_align">*Occupation : </td>
   <td>
      <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="student" />Student<br />
      <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="business" />Business<br />
      <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="pvtsect" />Priavte Sector<br />
      <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="govtsect" />Govt. Sector<br />
      <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="others" />Others<br />
   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td class="right_align">*On which project you want to work :</td>
   <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="" ="projectname" value="shine"/>Project Shine<br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="" ="projectname" value="sahyog" />Project Sahyog<br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="" ="projectname" value="smile" />Spreading Smiles                                                                              
   </td>
</tr>
</pre>
```

Comment: did you googling before ask here ?

Comment: you use whatever is appropriate for the data you are storing, the datatype names are pretty self explanitory, varchar,text are for text, datetime are for date times, int is for integers so on and so forth.

Comment: You can use, what you want. You can save checkbox value in BLOB or TEXT if you want ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you will get string as the value of radio so it will be varchar type

2) for check boxes any one can have multiple values so you need to create a separate table(working_project) for this values( data type will be same as radio) and another table for mapping(user_working_project)

user_working_project table will containing user id and working project id

e.g one user has id=1, and working_project=1,2

then in your user_working_project table entries will be like this:

```
  user_working_project_id working_project_id user_id
  1                         1                    1
  2                         2                    1
```